# open mp3 or apk file from webview

Tags: streaming, mp3, webview

I would like to know how I can open a Mp3 file from within a webview, basically a link that points to an MP3 file which would then open up the standard media player. Is this possible? I know it is because it works on the default webbrowser so I was wondering why I can't get it to work on a standard webview. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
            return true;
        } else if (url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
                return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Robbe's answer is correct, however I ran into some headaches implementing this functionality, so you should note that you must be passing a DIRECT LINK to an mp3, it can't be a magical URL that ends up at an mp3 after several redirects, the loading wheel will spin and you will be prompted with a "Can not play the requested stream" message.